# How to create extra columns to a dataframe, that get their values from how often a string gets mentionend beforehand?

Tags: python, pandas

Overall still pretty new to python, so sorry in advance if I miss any super obvious solutions. I'm currently in the process of modifying and cleaning up some sports data. Currently the dataframe looks somewhat like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'date': ['01.01.2019', '02.02.2020', '03.03.2021', '04.04.2022'],
                'home_team_name': ['Golden State Warriors', 'Brooklyn Nets', 'Golden State Warriors', 'Chicago Bulls'],
                'away_team_name': ['Sacramento Kings', 'Chicago Bulls', 'Utah Jazz', 'Golden State Warriors'],
                'WL_home': ['W', 'L', 'L', 'L'],
                'WL_away': ['L', 'W', 'W', 'W']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'home_team_name', 'away_team_name', 'WL_home', 'WL_away'])

print(df)
```

Now i want to create 4 extra columns including the total amount of wins and losses of the teams playing eatch other. Which in case of the fourth game in this example would look like this:

```
example_data = {'date': ['01.01.2019', '02.02.2020', '03.03.2021', '04.04.2022'],
                'home_team_name': ['Golden State Warriors', 'Brooklyn Nets', 'Golden State Warriors', 'Chicago Bulls'],
                'away_team_name': ['Sacramento Kings', 'Chicago Bulls', 'Utah Jazz', 'Golden State Warriors'],
                'WL_home': ['W', 'L', 'L', 'L'],
                'WL_away': ['L', 'W', 'W', 'W'],
                'wins_home_team': [1, 0, 1, 1],
                'loses_home_team': [0, 1, 1, 1],
                'wins_away_team': [0, 1, 1, 2],
                'loses_away_team':[1, 0, 0, 1]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(example_data, columns = ['date', 'home_team_name', 'away_team_name', 'WL_home', 'WL_away', 'wins_home_team', 'loses_home_team', 'wins_away_team', 'loses_away_team'])

print(df2)
```

I`ve tried several for loop versions on this problem, but overall cant make it work so that only the Wins and Losses of the teams playing in a specific row get added to their overall record.

Edit:

```
win_record_home = 0
win_record_away = 0

for value, item in enumerate(df['WL_home']):
    if value == "W":
        win_record_home = win_record_home + 1
    else:
        win_record_away = win_record_away + 1
```

This is the one I am currently playing around with, thats why its still missing the other 2 columns. The one issue here is that the if function is obviously not working as intended since I get the sum of all rows in win_record_away. The second and probably more complicated issue is how i would iterate through each row seperatly to add to the respectives teams wins and losses.

Comment: Hi @Paul, please provide an example for loop that you produced the closest output to what is desired so that folks can provide answers to your specific question

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you made a small mistake calculating the total amount of W/L
on your `example_data`,anyway this code should get you want you need:

```
import pandas as pd


data = {'date': ['01.01.2019', '02.02.2020', '03.03.2021', '04.04.2022'],
                'home_team_name': ['Golden State Warriors', 'Brooklyn Nets', 'Golden State Warriors', 'Chicago Bulls'],
                'away_team_name': ['Sacramento Kings', 'Chicago Bulls', 'Utah Jazz', 'Golden State Warriors'],
                'WL_home': ['W', 'L', 'L', 'L'],
                'WL_away': ['L', 'W', 'W', 'W']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'home_team_name', 'away_team_name', 'WL_home', 'WL_away'])

home = df.pivot_table(index=["home_team_name", "away_team_name",'WL_home'], columns="WL_home", aggfunc="size", fill_value=0).reset_index()
home = home.rename(columns=({'W': 'wins_home_team', 'L': 'loses_home_team'}))
away = df.pivot_table(index=["home_team_name", "away_team_name",'WL_away'], columns="WL_away", aggfunc="size", fill_value=0).reset_index()
away = away.rename(columns=({'W': 'wins_away_team', 'L': 'loses_away_team'}))

results = df.merge(home, on=["home_team_name","away_team_name",'WL_home'], how="left")
results = results.merge(away, on=["home_team_name","away_team_name",'WL_away'], how="left")
```